# Advanced Django ORM query with operator.or_ fails with None Values

Tags: django, django-orm, django-queryset

I'm trying to query the database and exclude some rows that contain one of some certain stings.

My simplified model looks like this:

```
class Message(models.model)
    text = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

My query looks like follows:

```
import operator

ignored_patterns = ['<ignore>', ]

messages = Message.objects.exclude(
    reduce(operator.or_, (Q(text__contains=pattern) for pattern
                                                    in ignored_patterns))
)
```

The problem i have is, that somehow Messages that have `self.text = None`are excluded too.

I'm thankful for every hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use and condition in `exclude`:

```
exclude = reduce(operator.or_, (Q(text__contains=pattern) for pattern
                                                    in ignored_patterns))
nulltext = Q(text__isnull = False)
messages = Message.objects.exclude( nulltext & exclude )
```

Also, read about [use of null in strings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#null):

> Avoid using null on string-based fields such as CharField and
>   TextField because empty string values will always be stored as empty
>   strings, not as NULL.

Comment: Thanks @danihp, i just gave it a try and it worked like expected.

Also thanks for the hint not using `null=True`. I definitively will keep that in mind. Always happy to learn new python/django patterns.